# unable to decrypt from spring config server / cleint

Tags: encryption, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

I am trying to encrypt and decrypt config properties using Spring config server and client. I have spring boot applications (server and client), using server I have encrypted password property and at client I am trying to decrypt it using same key but getting error.
I am trying to enable the config server client to decrypt these properties initially encrypted by config server. 
Here are the steps I followed:

1. Install Full-strength JCE and replace 2 policy files in JRE lib/security
2. generate a key using keytool

   ```
   keytool -genkeypair -alias config-server-key -keyalg RSA \
   -keysize 4096 -sigalg SHA512withRSA -dname "CN=*.domain.com,OU=EUS,O=eusdom,L=City,S=WA,C=US" \
   -keypass keyPass -keystore config-server.jks -storepass keys3crt
   ```
3. Added cloud security dependency to the pom file (added these in both config server and client pom )

   ```
   <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-security-rsa</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.1.RELEASE</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
4. Added the encryption related configurations (the same values used by config server and client) to the `bootstrap.yml` also tried with `application.yml`

   ```
   encrypt:
   key-store:
       location: file:///D:/encrypt-server/config-server.jks
       password: keyPass
       alias: config-server-key
       secret: keys3crt
   ```
5. My config server bootstrap looks like this

   ```
   spring:
     application:
       name: config-service
     cloud:
       config:
           server:
               git:
                   uri: https://github.com/<>/spring-config-repo
               encrypt:
                   enabled: false
   server:
     port: 8888
   ```
6. Encrypt the passWord property using config server

   ```
   curl -X POST --data-urlencode d3v3L \  http://localhost:8888/encrypt
   ```
7. Try to decrypt the property using config server

   ```
   curl  http://localhost:8888/decrypt  -d <encryptedVale>
   ```

I am getting below error

```
    {"timestamp":1472667297292,"status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","exception":"java.lang.IllegalStateException","message":"Cannot decrypt","path":"/decrypt"}
```

8. I try to print the encrypted property using config client (note : I have added the depenencies and encrypt key details as per 3,4)

   ```
   @RefreshScope
   @Component
   @RestController
   public class Greeter {

   @Value("${cassandra.hostnames}")
   String hostnames;

   @Value("${cassandra.username}")
   String userName;

   @Value("${cassandra.password}")
   String passWord;

   @RequestMapping(value = "/", produces = "application/json")
   public List<String> index(){
       List<String> env = Arrays.asList(
           "userName is: " + userName,
           "passWord is: " + passWord,
   );
   return env;
   }
   ```

   }
9. I am getting `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot decrypt: key=cassandra.password` error
10. Note: I tried to decrypt in config server with out

    ```
     encrypt:
      enabled: false
    ```

    Please let me know if i am missing anything here. Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap configuration you using to enable asymmetric encryption is no longer enabled by default. If your project requires it, it can be re-enabled by properties or by a new starter.
Can find out guideline [here]
[1]: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-release/wiki/Spring-Cloud-2020.0-Release-Notes#breaking-changes

To enable the bootstrap in spring boot version greater than 2.3.x we need to add new starter dependency introduced by #SpringCloud.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
```