# Spring CLI/Spring Cypher Issue/s Did you configure the keystore correctly

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Trying to do a project with spring and cyphering the password. In http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/single/spring-cloud-config.html#_encryption_and_decryption

There is at least one issue there as key-store is called keystore but I haven't found someplace without that same issue to base my work on.

Only similar issue I found is 
[unable to decrypt from spring config server / cleint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39256589/unable-to-decrypt-from-spring-config-server-cleint)
but there are no responses there.

I have done the following 
Installed Full-strength JCE
Added this dependancy to the pom

```
<groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-security-rsa</artifactId>
```

I have two concerns. First I am trying to get it to work in Spring CLI like this:

1.- Create a key

```
keytool -genkeypair -alias mytestkey -keyalg RSA -dname "CN=Web Server,OU=Unit,O=Organization,L=City,S=State,C=US" -keypass letmein -keystore server.jks -storepass letmein
```

2.-Encrypt something as following works but I then will be able to decrypt it without using the password so I think that defeats the purpose.

```
spring encrypt mysecret --key @server.jks TEST
```

How are the commands for encrypting and decrypting suppose to be using the password?

I haven't been able to get it to work on my project but I believe the issue is center around how I created the key. I have configured the following in case someone sees another mistake.

Relevant part of my  boostrap.yml

```
encrypt:
  key-store:
  location: server.jks
  password: letmein
  alias: mytestkey
  secret: letmein
```

Relevant part of my application.yml

```
test:'{cipher}EncryptedValue got by Step 2'
```

This gets me the following error

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No decryption for FailsafeTextEncryptor. Did you configure the keystore correctly?
```

Answer (score 0):

We have had some similar problems and were able to decrypt after using a later version of the jdk. I think it was specifically jdk-8u-151 that was giving us problems. Upgrading to a later jdk fixed the issue. Hope that helps!!